# aggregation on Multiple LEFT JOIN performance issue (SQL SERVER)

Tags: sql-server, performance, aggregation

I have a performance issue regarding a quite simple query that run for more than 30 minutes:

```
SELECT   P.pID
    ,COUNT(T1.ID) AS NB1
    ,COUNT(T2.ID) AS NB2
    ,COUNT(T3.ID) AS NB3
    ,COUNT(T4.ID) AS NB4
    ,COUNT(T5.ID) AS NB5

FROM MainTable P 

LEFT OUTER JOIN Table1 T1 ON  P.pID = T1.pID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 T2 ON  P.pID = T2.pID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table3 T3 ON  P.pID = T3.pID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table4 T4 ON  P.pID = T4.pID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table5 T5 ON  P.pID = T5.pID

GROUP BY P.pID
```

Where as each query would reply in few ms:

ex.

```
  SELECT   P.pID
        ,COUNT(T1.ID) AS NB1

    FROM MainTable P 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Table1 T1 ON  P.pID = T1.pID

    GROUP BY P.pID
```

If I don't use any aggregation (COUNT or anything else) the query run in few ms:
ex.
    SELECT   P.pID

```
FROM MainTable P 

LEFT OUTER JOIN Table1 T1 ON  P.pID = T1.pID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 T2 ON  P.pID = T2.pID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table3 T3 ON  P.pID = T3.pID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table4 T4 ON  P.pID = T4.pID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table5 T5 ON  P.pID = T5.pID

GROUP BY P.pID
```

Obviously all indexes are set etc...
The only "slowing down" element is that pID is a varchar (50) but I can't change it and in my opinion this is not be the main problem here.

I used a workaround including union all that work fine but I really wondering why these is so long and how could I optimize this as aggregating over multiple left join are really common stuff in reporting project and should not be so slow.

thank you for your help.

[EDIT]
thx to **ARION** i got a nice query working really nice.

**But my main concern is about understanding what's wrong in the sql engine writing the query with multiple left join.**

Tables descr would be :

```
Table P (500 rows) 
pID varchar(50) NOT NULL as primary key
p.* doesn't matter 

Table Tn (between 2000 and 8000 rows)
Tn.ID int NOT NULL as primary key 
pID varchar(50) NOT NULL as Foreign key
```

[EDIT] Thanks to **Erland Sommarskog** on social.msdn.microsoft.com that point me my error of analyse.
-- detail about the answer

**Keep in mind :

LEFT JOIN forms cartesian product**

I was wrong assuming that the Cartesian product might have been filtered as I always refere to the same table.

thanks

Comment: we would need to see some data samples and table statistics

Comment: The problem of the original query is not (only) slowness. It could also give wrong results, if the `Tx` tables have rows with common `pID`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
SELECT
    P.pID,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table1 T1 WHERE P.pID = T1.pID) AS NB1,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table2 T2 WHERE P.pID = T2.pID) AS NB2,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table3 T3 WHERE P.pID = T3.pID) AS NB3,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table4 T4 WHERE P.pID = T4.pID) AS NB4,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table5 T5 WHERE P.pID = T5.pID) AS NB5

FROM MainTable P
```

Comment: HI thanks Arion this work just fine.
I'm still wondering why the query is so slow.
Do you have any idea?

Comment: Well I will probably anyway my main concern is about understanding what's wrong in the sql engine writing the query with multiple left join. That's why I would keep it open a bit longer except if you have a answer for me.

Comment: Ok. Sorry about that. I think that is because you are using a count on a varchar, then joining on it as well and then also grouping on it. You are doing the work more times then you need. You are processing more data then you are actually going to use with the unnecessary joins. If you are just interested in just the count this is the preferable solution.

Comment: Thanks but I checked using Count(tn.id) which are int. these didn't solve it.

Answer (score 2):

You could also rewrite the query by first grouping by (in subqueries), then joining:

```
SELECT
    P.pID,
    T1.NB1,
    T2.NB2,
    T3.NB3,
    T4.NB4,
    T5.NB5
FROM MainTable P 
  LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT pID, COUNT(*) AS NB1 FROM Table1 GROUP BY pID) AS T1
    ON T1.pID = P.pID
  LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT pID, COUNT(*) AS NB2 FROM Table2 GROUP BY pID) AS T2
    ON T2.pID = P.pID
  LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT pID, COUNT(*) AS NB3 FROM Table3 GROUP BY pID) AS T3
    ON T3.pID = P.pID
  LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT pID, COUNT(*) AS NB4 FROM Table4 GROUP BY pID) AS T4
    ON T4.pID = P.pID
  LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT pID, COUNT(*) AS NB5 FROM Table5 GROUP BY pID) AS T5
    ON T5.pID = P.pID
```

This would be useful if you want to include in the results other aggregates, besides the `COUNT(*)`, without having to run more correlated subqueries.

Comment: by the way using other aggregate function (like sum) works with **Arion** solution too

Comment: It works but you have to add another subquery in the `SELECT` list. I'm not sure if SQL-Server will properly optimize that (running one subquery only, both for COUNT and SUM).